# Calculating sum of vendor amounts in payment ledger

Tags: axapta, x++

I have a base class, then calls a subclass that retrieves values and outputs to a file.  There is a loop in the base calls that calls the subclass to generate all values until all lines are done in a ledger.
I would like to calculate the sum amount of each vendor.  So if there 10 records in a payment journal, 3 for vendor A, 3 for vendor B, 4 for vendor C.  I would like the sum of amount for each vendor based on their vendor id.  Is there a method or easy way in x++ to do this.  I was trying to use a static method in the base class and some how store the variable there and retrieve but i don't think it holds the value statically..

Answer (score 0):

You need to use a global variable in your class. Variable in your instance will hold value until this instance exists. Static methods do not belong to an instance and do not use global class variables. If you want to use static methods you need to return the calculated value from your static method and do something with it in your instance class method from which it was called.
For performance you can take a look at [caching](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh608239.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396) so you do not need to calculate values that were already calculated before.

Comment: Actually I got it to work by using a parm method and global variable in the base class. I realize in the sub class there are many instances being created and therefore only holds it temporary. Thats why i stored it in the base class which calls the sub class over and over. Since in the base class is where it is looping over and over. there isn't a new instance being created on the base class only the sub class. i was trying to do this from the get go, but i guess i was calling it differently and got it to work now